# jquery - count li in each of multiple ul and return value

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Using jQuery, how do I go through each nested ul.item, count the number of LI, and return that size/length in a parent span.someClass on that page?

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="someClass">3</span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="someClass">1</span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="someClass">2</span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show us what code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() { 
            var count = 0;
            $('ul').each(function(){
                if(count != 0){

                    var len = $(this).find('li').length;

                    $(this).parent().find('.someClass').html(len);
                }
                count++;

            })  
         });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><span class="someClass"></span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="someClass"></span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="someClass"></span>
    <ul class="item" style="display:none">
      <li>count me</li>
      <li>count me</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("ul.item").each(function() {
    // reusabilty
    var context = $(this);
    // count and populate
    context.prev(".someClass").text(context.children().length);
});
```

Omit `.someClass` in `prev()` call if these `span` elements are always immediately **before** your `ul` elements. In that case filtering in `prev` is not necessary and superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7kZQv/)**

```
 $('.someClass').each(function(){    
     $(this).text($(this).next('ul').find('li').length);
 })​
```

Comment: LIs are inside UL not inside SPAN.
`$(this).next('ul').find('li').length`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text` method:

```
$('.someClass').text(function(){
   return $(this).next().find('li').length
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EEsRR/

Answer (score 0):

```
​$("ul.item").each(function() {
    var _c = $(this);
    _c.siblings("span.someClass").html(_c.children("li").length);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough every `<li>` with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var howMany;
  // loop through every span.someClass
  $('.someClass').each(function(){
    // loop through every <li> within that span.someClass
    $('li').each(function(){
      // .index() is the current index of the $(this) object, it starts at 0, therefore .index()+1
      howMany = $(this).index()+1;
    });
    // Write your counted <li> in your <span> with .text(), manipulate the text within the <span> tags
    $(this).text(howMany);
  });
});
```

Did it work?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#yourelementid > li').length;
```

This will work for you instead of using any loop