# How to count how many <li> items are in a <ul> tag with a condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using `document.querySelectorAll('ul > li').length` to count how many items are in my list. Is there a way to count how many are there that answer a certain condition? e.g:

```html
<ul>
   <li>this.props.value</li>
   <li>this.props.value</li>
   <li>this.props.value</li>
   <li >this.props.value</li>
   <li>this.props.value</li>
</ul>
```

`this.props.value` can be equal to true/false. I need to count how many `<li>` tags are equal to true.

Comment: Please find below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498076/jquery-count-li-in-each-of-multiple-ul-and-return-value

Comment: @Yogesh im looking for a js solution. not Jquery.

Comment: Why not use the props data instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where do all of these items are coming from? If you have an array that you map to react elements then you can just perform a filter on that array and get the length.
For example:

```
myData.filter(x => x > 10).length
```

If you'll provide more details about your problem or a code sandbox example, it would be easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

Proper react way is to use a `ref` to `ul` and get the count of `li` using `ref.current.children.length`

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ul-li-count-vclcc?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const ListComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "li TRUE ",
      ref.current &&
        Object.values(ref.current.children).filter(
          li => li.innerText === "true"
        ).length
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul ref={ref}>
        <li>{"true"}</li>
        <li>{"true"}</li>
        <li>{"false"}</li>
        <li>{"true"}</li>
        <li>{"false"}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <ListComponent value="hello" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I assume OP uses state to render li elements so better to use that state to get how many items will be true instead of parsing the DOM.

Comment: Still, how do you check for the condition?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="menu">
        <li>true</li>
        <li>false</li>
        <li>true</li>
        <li>true</li>
        <li>false</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
        var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var countTrue = 0;
        var countFalse = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

            if (items[i].innerHTML === "true") {
                countTrue++;
            }
            else if (items[i].innerHTML === "false") {
                countFalse++;
            }
        }

        console.log("Total True is : " + countTrue);
        console.log("Total False is : " + countFalse);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```